# why echo element only show horizontally in a div

Tags: php, html, css

I am doing my home woke of php in which I would like to implement many `<a href="x">xx</a>` inside of a div.

the code is like this

```
echo "<div>";
for ($j = 1; $j <= $numElement; $j++) {
  echo "<a href=#$id class='button-primary-outlined'>$j</a>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

i have set the width of the div but what i got is like this[image]

all the `<a>` is placed horizontally.

what happens??

Comment: Wrap the anchor tag with a block type element say ```div``` or ```p```.

Comment: As @SajeebAhamed said, or you could just add a line breaker `<br>` tag after each `a` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Anchor element (*a*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is an [*in-line*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) element, you can make that a [*block-level*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element by setting the *display* property to *block*:

```
echo "<a style="display:block" href=#$id class='button-primary-outlined'>$j</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In summary, `<span>,<a>,<i>,<img>,...`  elements are used as an inline element and  `<div>,<form>,<main>,<p>,...` elements as a block level element.An inline element does not cause a line break (start on a new line) and does not take up the full width of a page, only the space bounded by its opening and closing tag
[This link separates all relevant tags](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

You can in css styling change this display mode tag from block to line and line to block by **display attribute**:
for example:

```
     <div style="display:inline">Hello World</div>
 // div tag is block level change to inline by display attribute
     <a style="display:block">Hello World</a>
 // a tag is inline level change to block level by display attribute
```